# Component Autocomplete VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create an `autocomplete` component, so I have the following code.

```
<Input v-model="form.autocomplete.input" @on-keyup="autocomplete" />
<ul>
    <li @click="selected(item, $event)" v-for="item in form.autocomplete.res">
        {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>

autocomplete(e){
    const event = e.path[2].childNodes[4]

    if(this.form.autocomplete.input.length > 2){
        this.Base.get('http://localhost:3080/post/search/post', {
            params: {
                q: this.form.autocomplete.input
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.form.autocomplete.res = res.data

            if(this.form.autocomplete.res.length > 0)
                event.style.display = 'block'
        })
    }
},
selected(item, e){
    this.form.autocomplete.item = item
    console.log(e)
}
```

however, how would I do to have the return after selecting my item in the main file?
Ex:

```
Home.vue

<Autocomplete :url="www.url.com/test" />
```

When selecting the item I want from my `autocomplete`, how do I get the return from it and store it in that file, as if I were using `v-model`?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage) said:

> Although a bit magical, v-model is essentially syntax sugar for
> updating data on user input events, plus special care for some edge
> cases.

Then at [Vue Using v-model in Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components),

> the `<input>` inside the component must:
>
> ```
> Bind the value attribute to a value prop
> On input, emit its own custom input event with the new value
> ```

Then follow above guide, one simple demo will be like below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('child', {

  template: `<div>
    <input :value="value" @input="autocomplete($event)"/>
    <ul v-show="dict && dict.length > 0">
        <li @click="selected(item)" v-for="item in dict">
            {{item.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>`,
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {
      dict: [],
      timeoutControl: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    autocomplete(e){
        /*
        const event = e.path[2].childNodes[4]

        if(this.form.autocomplete.input.length > 2){
            this.Base.get('http://localhost:3080/post/search/post', {
                params: {
                    q: this.form.autocomplete.input
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.form.autocomplete.res = res.data

                if(this.form.autocomplete.res.length > 0)
                    event.style.display = 'block'
            })
        }*/
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutControl)
        this.timeoutControl = setTimeout(()=>{
          this.dict = [{title:'abc'}, {title:'cde'}]
        }, 1000)
        this.$emit('input', e.target.value)
    },
    selected(item){
        this.selectedValue = item.title
        this.$emit('input', item.title)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testArray: ['', '']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child v-model="testArray[0]"></child>
  <child v-model="testArray[1]"></child>
  <div>Output: {{testArray}}</div>
</div>
```